# Drop a file being accessed by a WebBrowser control - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a program that allows users to index files in a database and then said files are moved to a fileserver.

Current when they import a pdf it is displayed in a WebBrowser control, with WebBrowser.Navigate, so that they can see the file and then select the required indexing information from drops down. When done the file needs to be moved and the original deleted.

However I am running in to a problem where viewing the file through the WebBrowser locks the file and it cannot be moved. I have tried getting the WebBrowser to point at another file but this doesn't seem to release the file from being accessed.

Is there a way, short of disposing of the WebBrowser at run time to force the program to release its lock on this file?

Comment: Use a copy of the file for the preview? Then collect the garbage when the Window/Form is closed. Btw, the WebBrowser doesn't show PDF files by itself, it's a PDF viewer plug-in. Maybe it doesn't release the file right away. Retry in a while,  after you navigate to a new or empty URL.

Comment: I did consider doing that but just wanted to check that there was another way round it before doing more copying of files and having clean up code to delete 'viewing' copies.